# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $Z(H)$ is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $Z(H)$ be the center of $H$. Show that $Z(H)$ is normal in $G$.

So I know that if $h' \in Z(H)$ then $h'h=hh'$ for all $h \in H$ and I tried proving that $gZ(H)=Z(H)g$. Let $h' \in Z(H)$, so $gh'=hg$ for some $h \in H$ since $H$ is normal and $Z(H)$ is a subgroup of $H$. In particular, $z(H)$ is normal in $H$, so $gh'g^{-1} \in Z(H)$. Therefore $h$ has to be in $Z(H)$. That proves that $gZ(H) \subseteq Z(H)g$. Similarly, we can prove the reverse inclusion. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: "In particular, $Z(H)$ is normal in $H$, so $gh'g^{-1} \in Z(H)$" - Why? $g$ is not necessarily in $H$.

Comment: Do you know about characteristic subgroups? If so, do you know the theorem that if $H \lhd G$ and $K$ is characteristic in $H$, then $K \lhd G$?

Comment: @Bungo: I did not know that theorem. Is there another approach?

Comment: Sure, I'll write a sketch as an answer. Just let me know if you want more details.

Comment: FYI, I rolled back your edit. It's better to leave your work intact even if it is not 100% correct. This way any comments and answers that refer to your work will still make sense, and also your question is less likely to be closed by people who don't like "problem statement questions" that don't show any work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to show that $Z(H)$ is normal in $G$. Take any element $z \in Z(H)$ and any $g \in G$. We need to show that $gzg^{-1} \in Z(H)$. First, note that $gzg^{-1} \in H$, since $z \in H$ and $H$ is normal in $G$. Now, given any element $h \in H$, we need to show that $h(gzg^{-1}) = (gzg^{-1})h$.

Since $H$ is normal in $G$, we have $hg = gk$ for some $k \in H$. Therefore:

$$h(gzg^{-1}) = (hg)zg^{-1} = (gk)zg^{-1} = g(kz)g^{-1} = g(zk)g^{-1} = gz(kg^{-1})$$

where we have used the fact that $kz = zk$ because $k \in H$ and $z \in Z(H)$. Now recall that $hg = gk$. Multiplying this equation on the left and right by $g^{-1}$ gives us $g^{-1}h = kg^{-1}$. Applying this to the rightmost expression in the chain of equalities above, we get $gz(kg^{-1}) = gz(g^{-1}h) = (gzg^{-1})h$, which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to prove that a subgroup is normal, it is always instructive to consider of which homomorphism it is the kernel.

Consider this sequence of group homomorphisms:
$$
H \to G \to Inn(G) \to Aut(H)
$$
where the first one is inclusion, the second one takes $g$ to conjugation by $g$, and the last one is restriction to $H$ (which makes sense because $H$ is normal).

The kernel of this composition is the set of $h \in H$ such that conjugation by $h$ is the identity on $H$. This set is exactly $Z(H)$.

Answer (score 0):

A subgroup $M$ of $G$ is called *characteristic* if it is invariant under Aut$(G)$, and one writes $M$ char $G$. The center and the commutator subgroup are examples of characteristic subgroups. A characteristic subgroup must be normal since it is invariant under the inner automorphisms in particular.

The above is a special case of the following:
$$M \text { char } N \unlhd G \Rightarrow M \unlhd G$$